# PHP variables in a String

Tags: php, templates

I have a string that contains variables in it, and I want to add the values of the variables into it, as I'm trying it, it simply spits out as a string instead of adding the values of the variables.

Here is my code

```
$vars = $item->toArray();

    extract($vars);
    echo ($message_tmpl);die;

    echo print_r($message_tmpl)die;
```

Variables are extracted to add the values, but it returns plain output instead of values.

$first_name is extracted through $vars

```
Output
'My message to $first_name';

It should be
'My message to John Doe';
```

thanks

Comment: `strtr` or `str_replace` is what you need.

Comment: @u_mulder i think, he didn't write this question like question) it is guide .

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: You need to learn the difference between _code_, and _data_. Although your problem description is very rudimentary and far from an actual [mre] as you are supposed to show when asking these types of question, I think it is pretty clear that you are dealing with the latter here - data. And data does not get parsed as PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this :

```php
$name = "Toto";

$info["age"] = "8yo";

echo "Hello {$name} who is {$info["age"]}";
```

will output :

`Hello Toto who is 8yo`

You can also use the strtr() function such as :

```php
$template = '$who likes $what';

$vars = array(
  '$who' => 'Toto',
  '$what' => 'fruits',
);

echo strtr($template, $vars);
```

you will get :
`Toto likes fruits`